# The method scrollto(string) is undefined for the type webdriver

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, scroll, appium

[I am unable to use scroll to method, I am getting red mark over that methiod. Please help me how to resolve this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gmqkg.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gmqkg.png)

Comment: you should paste your full code here. Not an image and that too half image

Comment: @manoj scrollTo() and scrollToExact were set to deprecated in 4.0.0 and removed in 4.1.0. Check out the source code -- https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/4.0.0/src/main/java/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidDriver.java. If you are using the latest appium-client then downgrade to version 4.0.0 or 3.4.1... Else have a look at this -- https://pioneer2k9.blogspot.in/2016/08/workaround-or-solution-for-deprecated.html. Maybe this works for you

Answer (score 0):

Use `driver.swipe()`

`driver.scrollTo()` is no more in appium.

Answer (score 0):

As state the `driver.swipe()` method is your best option as `scrollTo()` is no longer supported. You can however write a scrollTo method by using some clever math that I will leave to you. You will have to couple `el.location, el.size and screen size information`. Decent amount of work to do but could make your life easier in the long run.